# Docker container stuck after enter in container

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-registry

I have installed docker on my server and I have been using it for a few days successfully in my environment, suddenly It got stuck after container launch and operation.

[image: Docker Image, Container & Issue]

Comment: try `docker exec -it lamp bash`

Comment: @Henry Done. Thanks for the quick solution.